How to increase accuracy when scaling data from table in pgfplots
I try to plot data with a small range but a large offset (my x data is a time in seconds, ranging from 26400 to 264480) and seem to reach accuracy limits of pgfplots when scaling this data after reading from table: I want to display time in hours and therefore have to divide by 3600.
When reading the manual of pgfplots, I was expecting this to be no problem because of the internal FPU. However, the calculations result in a wrong plot.
The offset in the data can not be removed as the absolute time is important when comparing this plot with other ones in the document.
Scaling the original data works but violates my own rule of "only use base SI units in data files".
Scaling the x ticks works, but is confusing when defining axis ranges or \draw-ing in the plot as the unscaled values have to be used there.
Thus, my question is: How can I scale plot data read from table with a high numerical accuracy?
MWE: The data contains a step from y=0 to y=1 at x=264450 respectively 264450/3600=73.458333. The red line is drawn at this position, but the ploted data is displayed shifted for the solutions I usually prefer.
I am using Lualatex.
EDIT:
The inaccuracy I recognize is the different position of the step in the data and in the plot.
In the data, the step is from t=264449 to t=264451, thus, at t=264450 the data crosses y=0.5. The position t=264450 is marked by the red line.
264450 seconds are 73.4583 hours. However, the step is plotted at 73.457 or 73.4565 for the first 3 plots. This is an inaccuracy/wrong position of the step of 5 seconds in a plot displaying a time period of 18 seconds. In plot 1 and 3 even the shape is wrong.
Plot 5 shows the exact result, the step is displayed at the correct position. This is what I expect also from the other solutions. However, plot 5 needs pre-processing of my data file by an external program (there, the division /3600 has to be done).
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

% The most obvious one "/3600" does not work at all :-(
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        use fpu=true,
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}/3600, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Using alternative calculation *(1/3600) is better but still wrong (why does this make a difference? Mathemathically, this is identical)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        use fpu=true,
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}*(1/3600), y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% "x filter" seems to be identical to "x expr"
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        use fpu=true,
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        x filter/.code={\pgfmathdivide{#1}{3600}},
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% scaling ticks is confusing (axis limits and drawing coordinates are unscaled and do not match displayed values in final plot)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        use fpu=true,
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 264438,
        xmax = 264456,
        scaled x ticks = manual:{}{\pgfmathparse{#1/3600}}
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:264450,0)--(axis cs:264450,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% scaling the original data works (Why? The numerically required number of digits stays the same?!)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        use fpu=true,
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        73.44444444 0
        73.45805556 0
        73.45861111 1
        73.46666667 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Welcome. // Unfortunately I don't understand the kind of inaccuracy you recognize. Can you please rephrase it from a different perspective, best by EDITing your question? Perhaps a sketch of what you'd expect might help? Thank you

I don't know why this happen, as the pgfplotstable manual says that computations are done with IEEE double precision (section 4.3.2, Mathematical Operations). As a workaround, you can replace the division by a multiplication
\addplot[] table[x expr=0.000277778*\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]

(as 0.000277778 = 1/3600), or use LaTeX3 floats through \fpeval
\addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}*\fpeval{1/3600}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]

Example (I removed use fpu=true, as it is set by default):
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

% replace the division by a multiplication (0.000277778 = 1/3600)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=0.000277778*\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% use LaTeX3 floats
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        footnotesize,
        grid=major,
        every x tick label/.append style = {rotate=90,anchor=east,/pgf/number format/.cd,precision=3,fixed,fixed zerofill,/tikz/.cd},
        xmin = 73.455,
        xmax = 73.460,
        ]
        \draw [thick,red] (axis cs:73.458333,0)--(axis cs:73.458333,1);
        \addplot[] table[x expr=\thisrowno{0}*\fpeval{1/3600}, y expr=\thisrowno{1}]{
        264400 0
        264449 0
        264451 1
        264480 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



I prefer the solution \fpeval{1/3600} as this is more readable and uses the maximum numerical resolution / number of digits (see the slight difference in your plots). Thank you!

@Inor I was hoping you would have another answer, as the issue you pointed seems to contradict the manual.

@jilab: I was reading the manual once again and found this information: "The FPU’s relative precision is at least 1e-4 although operations like addition have a relative precision of 1e-6." My knowledge in numerical mathematics is limited, but for me this seems surprisingly bad (compared to C, numpy, Octave, ...). Anyway, 264450*1e-5 is in the range of the inaccuracy I encountered. Maybe multiplication is 1e-6 relative precision and therefore the rounding errors are not (yet) visible in my data.

@jilab: 1e-6 indeed seems to be the final limit. I did a quick test with modified data where the step occurs from 2644499 to 2644501 (one digit more than before). Thus, one second is now 0.4e-6 relative (1/2644500). In this case, the step is plotted at the wrong position (error: 1 second) even using the \fpeval{1/3600} approach. Note to myself: 1) TikZ/pgf has weak (but most of the time sufficient) math capabilities 2) It is an extraordinaryly well documented software

@Inor I think you can do better with \fpeval{\thisrowno{0}*1/3600}. See also these tests about l3fp accuracy (the LaTeX3 module behind \fpeval). Anyway, it's probably better to perform real calculations outside LaTeX.
